# Using general bivariate gaussian to extract marginal PDF from given bivariate PDF

Tags: gaussian, bivariate-distributions, marginal-distribution

I had a homework question to find the marginal probability density functions, $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$, given a join probability density function $p_{XY}(x,y)$.

I have solved the problem by integration i.e.

$$p_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{XY}(x,y)dy$$
$$p_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p_{XY}(x,y)dx$$

The problem is solved, and there were no stipulations on how we solve it - however the professor has hinted that we could have instead used the general bivariate form:

$$f(x,y)=\frac {1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} exp  \left( -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \left( \frac {x - \mu_x} {\sigma_x} \right)^2 + \left( \frac {y - \mu_y} {\sigma_y} \right)^2 - 2\rho \frac {(x - \mu_x)(y - \mu_y)}{\sigma_x 
\sigma_y} \right]  \right) $$

And solved for $\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma_x, \sigma_y,$ and $\rho$. Given some concrete joint bivariate Gaussian, expressed in terms of $x$ and $y$, how could I go about substituting into the general form and perhaps creating a system of equations to find the marginal distributions?

I don't want to post the exact question, as I'd like to be able to generalize the solution (any concrete example joint PDF would be fine), here is one I found from a textbook, if a concrete example is easier to work with:

$$f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{4e^{-(x-y)^2/2}}{y^2\sqrt{2\pi}}$$

(Textbook is [Introduction to Probability for Data Science](https://probability4datascience.com/download.html) - Question is Section 5, Exercise 5(b))

The above is **not** my homework question.

Comment: What's a concrete joint?

Comment: @Ali Sorry - I meant something like the example problem. I updated it to say "concrete example joint pdf" instead of how it was.

Comment: Sorry still not quite sure what you're trying to do. Is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75980/generating-marginal-pdf-of-multivariate-gaussian) of any interest?

Comment: @Ali I am trying to get the marginal probability from a joint probabilty. I have done it using integration, but my professor hinted we can use the general form of a bivariate gaussian (as seen in the post) to extract $\mu_x, \mu_y, \sigma_x, \sigma_y, \rho$ and then we can simply plug these into the single variable version of the standard gaussian formula to extract the marginal probability.

I assume there is some way to create a system of equations for each variable, plugging in values from the joint PDF

Comment: You've just repeated what you wrote in the question but it doesn't really make sense. Is plugging the formula you have for $f$ into the formulas you have for $p$ something you've already done? or something you'd like to do but are having trouble with?

Comment: @Ali I would like to do, and am having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not hard but it's a bit labour-intensive. If you know about characteristic functions (see the link I posted in the comments) that's probably a neater way to do it, and more easily generalised too.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \int p_{XY}(x,y)dy
  &=&
  \frac {1}{2\pi\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}} \int\exp\left(
    -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \left[ \left( \frac {x - \mu_{X}} {\sigma_{X}} \right)^2
    +\left( \frac {y - \mu_{Y}} {\sigma_{Y}} \right)^2
    - 2\rho \frac {(x - \mu_{X})(y - \mu_{Y})}{\sigma_{X} \sigma_{Y}} \right]
  \right) dy\\
  &=&
  \frac {1}{2\pi\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
  \int\exp\left(
    -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} \left[
      \left(
    \frac {y - \mu_{Y}} {\sigma_{Y}}
    - \rho \frac {x - \mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}
    \right)^{2}
  +\left(1-\rho^{2}\right) \left( \frac {x - \mu_{X}} {\sigma_{X}} \right)^2
  \right]\right) dy\\
  &=&
  \frac {1}{2\pi\sigma_{X}\sigma_{Y}\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
  \exp\left(
    -\frac{1}{2} \left(
      \frac {x - \mu_{X}} {\sigma_{X}} \right)^2\right)
  \int\exp\left(
    -\frac{1}{2\sigma_{Y}^{2}(1-\rho^2)} \left(
    y - \mu_{Y}
    - \rho\sigma_{Y} \frac {x - \mu_{X}}{\sigma_{X}}
    \right)^{2}
  \right) dy\\
  &=&
  \frac {1}{\sigma_{X}\sqrt{2\pi}}
  \exp\left(
    -\frac{1}{2} \left(
      \frac {x - \mu_{X}} {\sigma_{X}} \right)^2\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Note that one equivalent characterization of a multivariate normal random vector is that every linear combination of its components is univariate normal. Of course, if $(X,Y)$ is bivariate normal, this implies the trivial linear combinations

$$1\cdot X+0\cdot Y=X,\\
0\cdot X+1\cdot Y=Y,$$

are each univariate normal.

Comment: I am a bit of a stats noob, so a lot of that went over my head. I am not sure how this helps to answer the question

Comment: $(X,Y)$ bivariate normal implies $aX+bY$ is univariate normal for all constants $a,b$. My point was this is one of the many *definitions* of bivariate normal.

Comment: At least I think that's what your question was, right? i.e. How the marginal distributions of a joint bivariate normal are also normal

Comment: it was more to extract the marginal from a join bivariate, i.e. given $p_{XY}(x,y)$, find $p_X(x)$ and $p_Y(y)$. I did it through integration, but my professor had hinted we could use the standard form of the gaussian bivariate to solve for mean, std and $\rho$, then plug these into a standard of the univariate